# How to scrape webpages and extract information from them?

Tags: python, web-scraping, awk

As a student in chemistry, I repeatedly have to look up molecules and get their SMILES string. SMILES strings are a mechanism that help us recreate the molecule in all sorts of chemical software.

For example, consider Alanine. I will search Alanine and go to the [PubChem link](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/alanine#section=InChI-Key). There I will look for the "Canonical SMILES" section, and copy paste the SMILES string into the code I am using.

If it is just one molecule, I might as well do the above. However, I now have to do this for 20 molecules. This seems like a lot of googling, clicking, and copy-pasting.

Is there a way to automate this process? Are there python libraries I can use for such a process? Can you do the same tricks using grep/awk on information on webpages?

Comment: Use the REST APIs they offer

Comment: As a starting point check the man pages for `curl` and `xmllint`. Try to write a script that works for 1 such web page, then move on to doing it for multiple.

Answer (score 0):

The module I use to scrape webpages might be able to help? All of the other web scraping modules are really complicated but have more features. the requests module just gets the exact data from a website, if you scrape a .html document it would return somthing that looked like this `<html><head><title>test</title></head></html>`, just the raw data. it could be more helpful for getting more information but it can be a little bit more frustrating if you just want a specific part of the page.

the code to use it looks like this

```
import requests

data = requests.get("google.com")
print(data)
```

Before you do any of this most websites have an API that can return exactly the data you need from the site within your code, in the footer they should have a developers link if they have an API

To return the html document.
(make sure to pip install requests!)